# Find a possible f(x) and g(x)

Tags: functions, factoring

Do you think that it is possible to find a $f$ and a $g$ such that $f(x) \neq x$ and  $\forall x \gt 1, y \gt 1$  then

$$f\left({1\over 1-{1\over x}-{1\over y}}\right) = {1\over 1-{1\over g(x)}-{1\over g(y)}}$$

EDIT 1:

and

$$f(2x) = 2f(x)$$
$$g(2x) = 2g(x)$$

EDIT 2:

and

$$f(x) \gt 0$$
$$g(x) \gt 0$$

Comment: Do $f=-1$ and $g=1$ qualify? (maybe you mean $\forall x>0, y>0$ in the question—and wait, what happens if $x=y=2$?).

Comment: Sorry I added that f(2x)=2f(x)and g(2x)=2g(x)

Comment: The identity map works (for both f and g) provided x and y are non-zero: with a little work, you could probably deal with the cases x=0 and y=0. Are there any specific conditions f and g must satisfy (continuous, differentiable, etc)? Given more conditions on f and g might make it easier to determine if such functions even exist.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The identity is excluded in the question. The case x = 0 and y = 0 are not important I remove them in the question

Comment: Yes f and g are continuous

Comment: I restricted the domain to x > 1 and y > 1

Answer (score 0):

(began answering before the $f(2x)=2f(x),g(2x)=2g(x)$ was added)

$$f\left({1\over 1-{1\over x}-{1\over y}}\right) = {1\over 1-{1\over g(x)}-{1\over g(y)}}$$

Let $A(x)=\frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}, B(x)=\frac{1}{g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)},u=\frac{1}{x},v=\frac{1}{y}$. Then:

$$\frac{1}{A(1-u-v)}=\frac{1}{1-B(u)-B(v)}\implies A(1-u-v)=1-B(u)-B(v)$$

Now, let $C(x)=1-A(1-x)$, then:

$$C(u+v)=B(u)+B(v)$$

Letting $u+v=x$, this implies that $\forall \alpha, B(u)+B(x-u)$ must be constant in $u \implies \frac{d}{du}(B(u)+B(x-u))=0$

Thus $B'(u)-B'(x-u)=0$ for all $u$ *and* all $x$, meaning that $B'$ is constant and thus that $B(x)=mx+b$ for some $m,b$. This would lead to $C(x)=mx+2b$, and, working backwards:

$$\implies A(x)=1-m(1-x)-2b=mx+(1-2b-m)$$

$$\implies f(x)=\frac{x}{m+(1-2b-m)x}, g(x)=\frac{x}{m+bx}$$

[I realise I've made assumptions about differentiability - currently thinking about how to remove them]

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the delay before the f(2x)=2f(x),g(2x)=2g(x). Do you think that a solution exists satisfying the constraint ?

Comment: And also f(x) > 0, g(x) > 0 please

Comment: I restricted the domain to x > 1 and y > 1

Answer (score 0):

From $f(2x)=2f(x)$ and $g(2x)=2g(x)$, we can deduce that $\forall n\in\mathbb Z : f(2^nx)=2^nf(x)$ and $g(2^nx)=2^ng(x)$.

So from

$$f\left({1\over 1-{1\over x}-{1\over y}}\right) = {1\over 1-{1\over g(x)}-{1\over g(y)}}$$

when $x=y$, and using $f(2x)=2f(x)$ and $g(2x)=2g(x)$, we can get to

$$f\left(\frac{1}{x-1}+1\right)=\frac{1}{g(x)-1}+1\quad (1)$$

In fact, using our first deduction, we obtain a more general form

$$f\left(\frac{1}{x-{1\over2^n}}+2^n\right)=\frac{1}{g(x)-{1\over2^n}}+2^n,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb Z\quad (2)$$

Since both $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we can work with limits. In $(2)$, when $n\rightarrow\infty$, the result is also infinite. More generally, this means that $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x$ approaches infinity.

Knowing this, let's try $x\rightarrow1^+$ in $(1)$ and solve for $g(1)$. We get $g(1)=1$. Thus $g(2^n)=2^n\quad \forall n\in\mathbb Z$.

My input doesn't really answer your question, but I hope it gives some insight for what to expect.

Comment: Also, if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, you can deduce that $f(1)=1$ as well.